# Getting error "The system cannot find the file specified" on compiling Java program using Process.StartInfo

Tags: java, process.start

Getting error:

> "The system cannot find the file specified"

when trying to compile Java program using `Process.Start()`. It works fine on my pc but getting error when deployed on the server. Please help me out.
Thanks.

Below is my code:

```
public void CompileJava(string path, string Qid)
{   
  Process jcprocess = new Process();
  jcprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
  jcprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "javac";
  jcprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = path+"Main.java";
  lbl_Test.Text = jcprocess.StartInfo.Arguments.ToString();
  jcprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  jcprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  jcprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  jcprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  jcprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  jcprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  jcprocess.Start();
}
```

Comment: Add File.Exists() and Directory.Exists() to your code before doing the call.
At least until you get it working, remove the Hidden flag and give yourself a console turd error if it can't find them.

Comment: Ahh.. you are relying on javac being in the path.  Open a cmd.exe on the server and make sure javac is in the path.

Comment: File.Exists() returned true and  removed the hidden flag

Comment: Oh.. I almost forgot.  Instead of path+"Main.java", you should use Path.Combine(path, "Main.java);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost certainly javac not being in your path on that machine.
Either add the whole path to javac (not suggested) or add the path to javac to your environment.  Why I say "not suggested" is because there might be other things javac might need to find in the same path.

If that doesn't work.. 
You can try this way that NEVER FAILS when 'file not found' or similar happens with ANY app.. not just yours.

1. Get the free sysinternals process monitor.
2. Open it and add a filter (it is menu [Filter]->[Filter])
3. Add "Process Name" "is" (or contians) "YourWinformApp.exe" [OK]
4. Clear the list and do the thing that breaks.
5. Right click on "SUCCESS" in the result column and "Exclude 'SUCCESS'"
6. Your answer should be right there in your face.

Good luck!